# VBA Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library in Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, user-interface, ms-access, ms-word, reference

I have an Access front-end app accessing "Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library" (Alt+F11 (VBA) -> Tools -> References).

It used to work before. Today, when the Access front-end tries to open up a word document through the UI, it shuts the entire Access front-end without any error message.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Are you sure that's the cause? have you tried stepping through it? You may want to include the relevant code (in your question) and point out which exact line it happens on. (Also, try rebooting, that can fix weird issues quickly) Another thing to try is to test it on a different machine and see if it does the same thing.

Comment: Also, try removing and re-selecting the reference to the Word object library.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment! I tried to reboot, re-select the references but no luck. What's weird about this is other machines are fine. (using the exact same application (same location)). Is there any ways that I can step through the VBA code while running the access front-end app? Appreciate it